# How do I change the User Stories 's order in the iteration Board?

Tags: azure-devops

I am having this issue that i want to change the order in which tasks are shown in my iteration board. For task within a user Story (US), is as simple as drag and drop, but for task in different US, it is not so.

It would be enough for me to change the order of US, just to show that we 've got to do first all the task within a US, and then all the task within another US.

I have tried to set priority or points data in order to do this, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can not drag and drop user stories directly in task board**. But you can drag and drop in the backlog Tab firstly.

There has an user voice [Allow drag and drop on task board with touch devices](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19847959-allow-drag-and-drop-on-task-board-with-touch-devic) which suggest the similar feature, you can vote and follow up.

**The workaround to change the user stories order can be done in backlog Tab**. Detail steps as below:

In task board -> Backlog Tab -> change user stories order by drag and drop -> then the order will be changed in task board.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, you can't. Not in the board, nor in the backlog for the iteration. Keep in mind I am talking about the iteration board.

Comment: I expanded my answer for the workaround, and you can have a try.

Comment: Yes! I don't know why i did not see it before! thanks!